# How to access Fracture Cells / Fracture Modifier in Blender 2.80?

Tags: modifiers

I recently switched to Blender 2.80 and while trying to do some modelling using old online tutorials, I found that Blender 2.80 doesn't seem to have Fracture Cells / Fracture Modifier feature at where it was in previous versions. Was it removed, renamed, or is there a new way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

I got a few answers across multiple channels:

`#blender` on irc.freenode.net:

> d33tah, try #blenderfracture (might need to wait for a response)

A thread on [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-access-fracture-cells-fracture-modifier-in-blender-2-80/1151367):

> It has been removed for now, 2.8+ will get mantaflow which is much better for that stuff. It was supposed to be in the 2.8 release but they fell behind, So now they are shooting for 2.81.

An answer on blender.chat:

> Fracture modifier has never been part of Blender releases. It’s a separated branch that will be merged at some point in the 2.8x releases. But you can download a fracture modifier build from graphicall.org.